# Store multiple values from a loop in R

Tags: r

what I'm trying to do is to store the values from a loop in a data frame or matrix. I'm performing a loop on every column. Below is my code:

```
library(forecast)
#> Warning: package 'forecast' was built under R version 3.4.3
library(plyr)
library(data.table)
#> Warning: package 'data.table' was built under R version 3.4.2

# Create a list into a data frame
df <- iris
dfFitList <- lapply(df[, c(1:4)], forecast::auto.arima)

# Lets unpack the list to extract fitted values into a data frame
dfFitList <- lapply(dfFitList, '[', 'fitted')

dfFit <- as.data.frame.list(dfFitList)
colnames(dfFit) <- names(dfFitList)

# I want accuracy measures of each column in matrix or data frame
result <- result()
result <- vector("double", ncol(df))
for(i in 1:ncol(dfFit)){
  result[i] <- accuracy(dfFit[,i], df[,i])
}
```

However what I get is a single vector with a list of accuracy values. Ideally, what I'm trying to get is a matrix (or data frame, can be anything, list too) with the columns as my variables from the dfFit data frame above and the rows to be the accuracy measures, or vice versa. If anyone could give me a hint or suggestion that'd be great, or a way to avoid a loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or wihtout looping :

```
result <- mapply(accuracy, dfFit, df[,1:4])
```

You will obtain on line by measure (the first one is the ME .. and so on).

Answer (score 1):

Just change the last part of your code to

```
# I want accuracy measures of each column in matrix or data frame
result <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:ncol(dfFit)){
  result <- rbind(result, accuracy(dfFit[,i], df[,i]))
}
```

This way you get a data.frame

```
> result
                   ME      RMSE       MAE          MPE      MAPE
Test set   0.04640401 0.5749977 0.4458530  0.005439232  7.492768
Test set1 -0.01435534 0.3643447 0.2775165 -1.831541188  9.410330
Test set2  0.05347604 0.5993159 0.3976608 -0.107065678 10.619752
Test set3  0.03005063 0.2744120 0.1905677 -4.529769486 22.043794
```